# What exactly happens when you print output in Java?

Tags: java, printing, system.out

Can anyone explain, what exactly happens in the following line?

```
java.lang.System.out.print("string" + i);
```

It will print "string" followed immediately by value of integer `i`, but what is happening here?

What is the significance of every part of this line?

Comment: What about you read some Java tutorials? It's not a programming question

Comment: @Guillaume - to be fair it *is* a programming question, it's just one that the OP should have done some research on before asking.

Comment: Using standard conventions `i` is an integer, but the rules don't actually require it.  Maybe `Object i = new Object ( ) { public String toString ( ) { throw new RuntimeException ( ) ; } } ;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`java.lang` is the package, which isn't needed with the correct `import` statement. `System` is a class in the `java.lang` package. `out` is a static public field (requires no bound instance, like a global variable) in the `System` class which has type `PrintStream`.

> A PrintStream adds functionality to another output stream, namely the
>   ability to print representations of various data values conveniently.
>   Two other features are provided as well. Unlike other output streams,
>   a PrintStream never throws an IOException; instead, exceptional
>   situations merely set an internal flag that can be tested via the
>   checkError method. Optionally, a PrintStream can be created so as to
>   flush automatically; this means that the flush method is automatically
>   invoked after a byte array is written, one of the println methods is
>   invoked, or a newline character or byte ('\n') is written.

This `PrintStream` is connected behind the scenes to an `OutputStream` which can either be connected to IDE output or console output (via Java Native Interface).

The arguments to the `print` method `"string" + i` are concatenated using the `+` operator into a big string, which can be directly fed to the print method. `i` is a primitive `int` type so is temporarily converted in memory to `String` during concatenation. As for string concatenation optimisation behind the scenes:

> An implementation may choose to perform conversion and concatenation in one step to avoid creating and then discarding an
>   intermediate String object. To increase the performance of repeated
>   string concatenation, a Java compiler may use the StringBuffer class
>   (§20.13) or a similar technique to reduce the number of intermediate
>   String objects that are created by evaluation of an expression.
>
> For primitive objects, an implementation may also optimize away the creation of a wrapper object by converting directly from a
>   primitive type to a string.

Answer (score 0):

`"string" + i` is performing String concatenation, creating a new String with the contents of `string123`, for example.

`java.lang.System.out.print` (typically abbreviated to `System.out.print`) then writes that String to the "standard output" - typically the console running the program.

Answer (score 0):

`java.lang.System` is qualified name of `System` class that resides in `java.lang` package. You're requesting its method `print` which supposes to get `String` value as the argument. Being called the method sends the resulting object in the brackets (cast to `String` ) to the default output (that is usually the console).

Answer (score 0):

From the [String javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html):

> The Java language provides special support for the string concatenation operator ( + ), and for conversion of other objects to strings. String concatenation is implemented through the StringBuilder(or StringBuffer) class and its append method. String conversions are implemented through the method toString, defined by Object and inherited by all classes in Java. For additional information on string concatenation and conversion, see Gosling, Joy, and Steele, The Java Language Specification.

So `"string" + i` gets turned into:

```
new StringBuilder("string").append(i).toString();
```

and then is passed to `System.out.print()`

Answer (score 0):

It is a method, that will show your message on the command line and there is another way to show your message in window, write:

```
JOptionPane.showMassageDialog(null,"your message");
```